# Changing LibreOffice to Russian

Tags: language-support

On my PC, I lost the administrator password, and the default system language is English. How can I change LibreOffice from English to Russian?

Answer (score 5):

1. Follow [the instructions to reset a lost administrative password](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/616451) so that you can run `sudo` commands
2. Install the Russian localization by opening a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running:

   ```
   sudo apt install libreoffice-l10n-ru myspell-ru hyphen-ru libreoffice-grammarcheck-ru libreoffice-help-ru mythes-ru
   ```
3. Open LibreOffice
4. Go to the `Tools` menu, then `Options…`
5. On the left of the window, click the  to the left of `Language Settings`
6. Click on `Languages`

   [image: Languages options]
7. For `User interface`, select `Russian`
8. For `Locale setting`, select `Russian`
9. For `Western`, select `Russian`
10. Click `OK`
11. Restart LibreOffice